# How can I copy all of the users input and labels in a windows form page to another windows form page that is displayed in a table style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am using windows form app C# and I created one form (checklist) with labels and textboxes as well checkboxes. In my second form (test_results) page, I created a tablelayoutpanel with all of the data in the first form. The 'submit' button on my first form has. I chose the tablelayoutpanel because the form that I'm replicating is an excel form and the user wants it to look exactly like it does in excel. The results are showing up when I run this but as you can see this is only for 3 textboxes on the tablelayoutpanel which actually has about 25. I'm just not sure this is the best practice and simplest way. Please see my code below for both forms

Form1

```
namespace IppInspectSheet
{
    public partial class checkList : Form
    {
        public checkList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetValueForText1 = textBox1.Text;
            SetValueForText2 = textBox2.Text;
            SetValueForText3 = textBox3.Text;
            test_results_Label t = new test_results_Label();
            t.Show();
            //Form3 f = new Form3();
            //f.Show();


        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static string SetValueForText1 = "";
        public static string SetValueForText2 = "";
        public static string SetValueForText3 = "";
```

Form2

```
namespace IppInspectSheet
{
    public partial class test_results_Label : Form
    {
        public test_results_Label()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void test_results_Label_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = checkList.SetValueForText1;
            textBox2.Text = checkList.SetValueForText2;
            textBox3.Text = checkList.SetValueForText3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _In my **second** form page, I created a **tablelayoutpanel**_ - where DataGridView coming from then?

Comment: What is appearing? How did you save the input in form1? And how did you present data in form2? [`tablelayoutpanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel?view=net-5.0) is not a good choice to present data.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms is UI framework which responsible to display given data structure and provide user input values to that data structure.

You can create an type which will represent your data in Form1

```
public class MyData
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Form1 "bind" this data to form controls. [Data Binding and Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data-binding-and-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

```
public class Form1
{
    private readonly MyData c;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _data = new MyData();

        textbox1.Bindings.Add("Text", data, nameof(data.One), true, DataSourceUpdateMode .OnPropertyChanged);
        textbox2.Bindings.Add("Text", data, nameof(data.Two), true, DataSourceUpdateMode .OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2(_data);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Add parameter in constructor of Form2, so we can pass data to it.

```
public class Form2
{
    private readonly MyData _data;
    public Form2(MyData data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _data = data;

        label1.Bindings.Add("Text", data, nameof(data.One));
        label1.Bindings.Add("Text", data, nameof(data.Two));
    }
}
```